# Ackermann function in terms of higher order recursion

Tags: logic, computer-science, computability, ackermann-function

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) provides a higher-order definition of Ackermann function. First it gives the normal recursive definition
\begin{equation*}
A(m,n)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
n+1 & \text{if $m=0$} \\
A(m-1,1) & \text{if $m>0$ and $n=0$} \\
A(m-1,A(m,n-1)) & \text{if $m>0$ and $n>0$.}
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation*}
After which it provides higher-order formulas
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{lcl}
A(0)&=&S\\
A(m+1)&=&I(A(m))
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
where $S$ is successor function and I is defined as
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{lcl}
I(f)(0)&=&f(1)\\
I(f)(n+1)&=&f(I(f)(n)).
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

I don't follow the construction. I computed some small values of $m$ and it seems correct compared to the table provided in Wikipedia, but how would one prove these two definitions equal?

Comment: Did you try induction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quoted definitions will be awkward to work with, since the first definition uses $A$ for a binary function while the second uses $A$ for a unary, function-valued function (the "curried" form of the first $A$).  I suggest using different symbols; for example, write $B$ instead of $A$ in the higher-order version.  Then what you want to prove is that $A(m,n)=B(m)(n)$.  This should be doable by a double induction; start doing an induction on $m$, and within its induction step you'll do an auxiliary induction on $n$. An additional awkwardness arises from the fact that the first definition writes the induction step as going from $m-1$ to $m$ while the second goes from $m$ to $m+1$; I'd suggest changing variables in one of the two to make them match up.